# How to Enable Maintenance mode for specific store in Multi Website Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore, multi-website, maintenance

I have multi websites, I set website or store code in server conf that's is $_SERVER

Now I have to enable maintenance flag or page only for specific store  rest other store should

So how to do it ? any suggestion ?

Answer (score -2):

If your installations have different IP addresses, you can use this

```
magento maintenance:enable [--ip=<ip address> ... --ip=<ip address>] | [ip=none]
magento maintenance:disable [--ip=<ip address> ... --ip=<ip address>] | [ip=none]
magento maintenance:status
```

--ip= is the IP you want to **exempt** from maintenance mode

It's even in the docs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-maint.html

Comment: No it doesn't. Try reading the docs before you make false statements - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-maint.html

Comment: Downvoted = (from the docs) The --ip=<ip address> option is an IP address to exempt from maintenance mode (for example, developers doing the maintenance).. Using the --ip flag for enabling maintenance mode on a single store view in a multi-store environment would not work. 

Resource: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/tutorials/maintenance-mode.html?lang=en